# Windows: how to get the current time in milliseconds in c++？

Tags: c++, windows, time

I want to get the current time in milliseconds. I have tried to get systemtime and filetime.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460676/linux-and-windows-milisecond-time

Comment: And exactly what is "wrong" when you use `SystemTime`?

Comment: #include <time.h> 

And then look up a tutorial on using time.h in c++ :)